# How to assign values to image array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, density-independent-pixel

I am trying to write a matlab code which copies one segment of an image into another with a particular range matrices.
My code works as required. The only problem I am having is that I want to assign 255 value to copied part of image so that the image appears on white background rather than black background

```
a=imread('/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/toolbox/images/imdata/cameraman.tif');
    a=double(a);
    b=zeros(256,256);
    for i =0:1:255
        for j=0:1:255
        if((i>=97 && i<=150)&&(j>=34 && j<=81))
        b(j,i)=a(j,i);
    %    else
    %         b(j,i)=255;
        end
        end
    end
    imshow(a,[]);
    figure,imshow(b,[]);
    imageSegmenter(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing your matrix to `zeros` simply initialize it to `255`.

```
b = 255 + zeros(256, 256);
```

As a side-note, MATLAB uses 1-based indexing so you should change your `for` loop indices to reflect that:

```
for i = 1:size(b,2)
    for j = 1:size(b, 1)
        % Do stuff
    end
end
```

Better yet, you can completely remove the `for` loop.

```
b = 255 + zeros(256, 256);
b(34:81, 97:150) = a;
```

Comment: When I am trying to remove for loop and in place of hard coded values I am trying to take values into variables x1, x2, y1, y2 and put in I am getting error.

b(x1:x2,y1:y2) = a;